# как при раскрытии блока сменить название кнопки?

Tags: javascript

```
  <td><a href="#area[[+id]]" title="">Смотреть</a> </td>
```

при нажатии раскрывается блок с контентом, как сделать чтобы при раскрытом блоке вместо смотреть была надпись Закрыть?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/manager/templates/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: К вопросу следует добавить код, в котором обозначена ваша проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант - сделать два спана для текста

```js
var cnt = $('div span');

cnt.click(function(){
    cnt.toggle();
})
```

```css
div .close{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class='open'>Раскрыть</span>
    <span class='close'>Закрыть</span>
</div>
```

---

*привёл бы код - ответил бы фиксом в твой код, а так - какой вопрос, такой ответ :)*

Comment: о, я ещё короче извращение придумал: var cnt = $('div span'); cnt.click(cnt.toggle.bind(cnt, 0))

Comment: извините <script>
    var cnt = $('div span');

cnt.click(function(){
    cnt.toggle();
})

</script> я правильно пишу?)

Comment: @reddyk, возможно, хотя, скорее всего, подобные строки должны быть внедрены и адапрированы в ваш код и прямое копирование оных ничего не даст